# Upload File using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am new to django. Can anybody help me... How can I upload a file using the Rest Framework API ?

I have tried following this page:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

Comment: What did you tried atcually? Atleast paste some code.

Comment: I have tried same code which is given in above link.. Now i am not able to test.. how to test ?

Comment: @user2709881 check out this [blog post](http://ariejan.net/2010/06/07/uploading-files-with-curl/)

Answer (score 13):

File uploading in Django REST framework is the same with uploading files in multipart/form in django.

To test it you can use curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u {username}:{password} \
-F "{field_name}=@{filename};type=image/jpeg" http://{your api endpoint}
```

Other fields are just like normal form fields in Django.

Comment: so what if your curl has json data and an image at the same time?

Comment: I think you can add those data as form field data as well (in -F parameter). Forgot what I did since I haven't been working on REST framework for a few months now.

Comment: Leonid: Did you get the answer of your question. can we json data and image at the same time.

Comment: @Leonid check out this code https://github.com/zheli/duego-photo-gallery. I remember I succeed with this one. You can look into the test for upload in rest_api app.

Comment: @Zhe I can't get the test APIClient to upload files - I keep getting a UnicodeDecodeError on the .post call. Did you have to do anything to get this to work?

Comment: @RobinElvin probably because the project was done long time ago and it is out of update now.

Answer (score 2):

Zhe answer is pretty well. Besides, you can add some parameters in order to see the response. Take this one for example:

```
curl -X PATCH --dump-header - -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u jorge:123456 -F "image=@/home/oscar/Pictures/dgnest/_MG_6445.JPG;type=image/jpeg" http://localhost:8000/api/project/3/
```