# Django Rest_Framework File upload using Ajax

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-file-upload

I'm beginner of django rest_framework.

I want to implement file upload feature to my project,
and I did some search, but I could not get any helpful example.

So, is there somebody who can tell me some reference or example in rest framework file upload?

Answer (score -1):

Uploading a file using Django Rest Framework can be done independently from the method that you are using to send the request (Ajax in this case). 
You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422803/upload-file-using-django-rest-framework) to have more information about how it is done